# Dynamically Allocated Array of Structures: Assignment Issues (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

It's the last problem of the set.  I need to created a dynamically allocated array of structures, and then I must access the data in these structures to insert into the output stream.  Problem is, the compiler I'm using (g++) won't accept the way I'm assigning values to the structures in the array.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct candy
{
        string name;
        float weight;
        int cal;
};

int main()
{
        candy * pc = new candy [3];
        pc[0] = {"ChocoBar", 4.5, 230};
        pc[1] = {"SugarCrack", 9.3, 690};
        pc[2] = {"TamponBar", 1.3, 100};

        cout << "Bar None:\n";
        cout << "Name: " << pc[0].name << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << pc[0].weight << endl;
        cout << "Calories: " << pc[0].cal << "\n\n";
        cout << "Bar One:\n";
        cout << "Name: " << pc[1].name << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << pc[1].weight << endl;
        cout << "Calories: " << pc[1].cal << "\n\n";
        cout << "Bar Two:\n";
        cout << "Name: " << pc[2].name << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << pc[2].weight << endl;
        cout << "Calories: " << pc[2].cal << "\n\n";

        delete [] pc;
        return 0;
}
```

Having defined the structure type -- candy; and created a pointer(pc) to hold the address in memory assigned for three structures by *new*, I then attempted to assign values to the three structures.  However, the compiler spit out a message saying that "extended initializer lists are not available...", which tells me that I botched the code such that the compiler doesn't even recognize my structure type as a structure (otherwise it would accept my list of three values).
I've just today learned of arrays, structures, pointers, and dynamic allocation of variables, and when it comes to arrays of structures statically assigned, and structures and arrays dynamically assigned (separately), I completed the exercises on the first try; but dynamically-assigned arrays of structures are giving me copious grief.
Please help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (see it run [here](http://ideone.com/QVwOCz) with GCC 4.8.1), but it does use C++11 features - are you sure you're compiling with those enabled?  i.e. `-std=c++11` on the compiler command line?  Do you have a recent enough GCC version?

Comment: @TonyD It compiles by chance (no `<string>` header.)

Comment: When you are using array such as: pc[0], then you are making a reference to the first element in an array, which in your case happen to be a candy Object. So pc[0] is a reference to a candy and not a block of memory. I would suggest that you first initialize your candy object, then add it to the pointer of an array. You might need to do something like: pc[0].name = "ChocoBar"; pc[0].weight = 4.5; pc[0].cal = 230; and then to print you need to: cout<<"Name: " << pc[0].name <<endl; cout<<"Weight: " << pc[0].weight <<endl; and so on.

Comment: @Juniar What they are trying to do is fine. It just requires C++11.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to include the `<string>` header for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Second, you need to ensure your compiler supports C++11. That would make the following code legal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    // for std::string

struct candy
{
  std::string name;
  float weight;
  int cal;
};

int main()
{
  candy* pc = new candy[3];
  pc[0] = {"ChocoBar", 4.5, 230}; // requires C++11
  delete [] pc;
}
```

Next, you can learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), a class template that does the dynamic memory allocation/de-allocation for you, and can resize its storage, effectively acting like an array that can grow in size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct candy
{
  std::string name;
  float weight;
  int cal;
};

int main()
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  using std::vector;

  vector<candy> pc;
  pc.push_back({"ChocoBar", 4.5, 230});
  pc.push_back({"SugarCrack", 9.3, 690});

  for (size_t i = 0; i < pc.size(); ++i)
  {
      cout << "Name: " << pc[i].name << endl;
  }
}
```

Note that in C++11 you can also initialize the vector with a set of elements:

```
std::vector<candy> candies{{"ChocoBar", 4.5, 230},
                           {"SugarCrack", 9.3, 690},
                           {"TamponBar", 1.3, 100}};
```

Comment: That was fast.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, installed g++-4.9, and completely updated and upgraded my OS; yet the compiler still spewing the same error messages.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @user3179580 Use the flag `-std=c++11`.